# Specify color of class using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, algorithm

Refering to a live codepen demo at [here](https://codepen.io/Maximusssssu/pen/MWrzpav?editors=0111). When you click on the grid, it will display blue arrows. Is there a way to specify the color of arrow displayed using javascript? I only know how to specify the colour using css but i needed the colour specification to be in Javascript so that it can be manipulated by the user :) Thank you for reading and have a nice weekend :)

[image]

```
 .red-dot {
      position:absolute; 
      width:55px; 
      height:55px;
      background:blue;
      pointer-events: none;
    clip-path: polygon(57% 0, 58% 48%, 75% 49%, 49% 100%, 22% 49%, 39% 48%, 39% 0);
    
    }
```

Comment: You need to show how you add the arrow to the grid.

Comment: I add the arrow to the grid using clippath

Comment: You do more than that. Please show the relevant code, particularly the JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this:

```js
newDot.style.background = '<your background here>';
```